# Coroutines Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines

I have a Parent and Child model

This is my Parent Model

```
data class LastMatch(
val events: List<Event>)
```

This my Child Model

```
data class Event(
val dateEvent: String,
val dateEventLocal: Any,
val idAPIfootball: String,
val idAwayTeam: String,
val idEvent: String,
val idHomeTeam: String,
val idLeague: String,
val idSoccerXML: Any,
val intAwayScore: String,
val intAwayShots: Any,
val intHomeScore: String,
val intHomeShots: Any,
val intRound: String,
val intSpectators: Any,
val strAwayFormation: Any,
val strAwayGoalDetails: Any,
val strAwayLineupDefense: Any,
val strAwayLineupForward: Any,
val strAwayLineupGoalkeeper: Any,
val strAwayLineupMidfield: Any,
val strAwayLineupSubstitutes: Any,
val strAwayRedCards: Any,
val strAwayTeam: String,
val strAwayYellowCards: Any,
val strBanner: String,
val strCity: Any,
val strCountry: String,
val strDescriptionEN: Any,
val strEvent: String,
val strEventAlternate: String,
val strFanart: Any,
val strFilename: String,
val strHomeFormation: Any,
val strHomeGoalDetails: Any,
val strHomeLineupDefense: Any,
val strHomeLineupForward: Any,
val strHomeLineupGoalkeeper: Any,
val strHomeLineupMidfield: Any,
val strHomeLineupSubstitutes: Any,
val strHomeRedCards: Any,
val strHomeTeam: String,
val strHomeYellowCards: Any,
val strLeague: String,
val strLocked: String,
val strMap: Any,
val strOfficial: String,
val strPoster: String,
val strPostponed: String,
val strResult: Any,
val strSeason: String,
val strSport: String,
val strSquare: String,
val strStatus: String,
val strTVStation: Any,
val strThumb: String,
val strTime: String,
val strTimeLocal: Any,
val strTimestamp: String,
val strTweet1: Any,
val strTweet2: Any,
val strTweet3: Any,
val strVenue: String,
val strVideo: Any)
```

This is my RetroBuilder

```
  private fun getRetrofit1(): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build() //Doesn't require the adapter}val apiService1: ApiService = getRetrofit1().create(ApiService::class.java)
```

This my Api Service

```
interface ApiService {

@GET("eventspastleague.php?id=4628")
suspend fun getLast(): LastMatch}
```

This is my API Helper

```
class ApiHelper(private val  apiService: ApiService) {

suspend fun getLast() = apiService.getLast()}
```

This My Repo

```
class MainRepository(private val apiHelper: ApiHelper) {

suspend fun getLast() = apiHelper.getLast()}
```

This is my ViewModel

```
class MainViewModel(private val mainRepository: MainRepository) : ViewModel() {

fun getLast() = liveData(Dispatchers.IO){
    emit(Resource.loading(data = null))
    try {
        emit(Resource.success(data = mainRepository.getLast()))
    }catch (exception: Exception){
        emit(Resource.error(data = null,message = exception.message ?: "Error Occured"))
    }
}
}
```

This is my View class

```
class MatchesView : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel
private lateinit var adapter: MatchesAdapter
private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
private var arrayList: ArrayList<LastMatch>? = null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_matches_view)
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewasd)
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar)

    setupViewModel()
    setupUI()
    setupObservers()
}

private fun setupViewModel() {
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(
        this,
        ViewModelFactory(ApiHelper(RetrofitBuilder.apiService1))
    ).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
}

private fun setupUI() {
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    adapter = MatchesAdapter(arrayListOf())
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(
        DividerItemDecoration(
            recyclerView.context,
            (recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).orientation
        )
    )
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
}

private fun setupObservers() {
    viewModel.getLast().observe(this, Observer {
        it?.let { resource ->
            when (resource.status) {
                Status.SUCCESS -> {

                    recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
```

//                        Log.d("data","Data: "+ resource.data)
resource.data?.let { users -> retrieveList(users)

```
                    }

                    Log.d("data","Data: "+ resource)
                }
                Status.ERROR -> {
                    recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    Toast.makeText(this, it.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
                Status.LOADING -> {
                    progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    recyclerView.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }
        }
    })
}

private fun retrieveList(users: List<Event>) {
    adapter.apply {
        addUsers(users)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}}
```

My problem is all the data that i need to display was on my child model. I want to pass the data from Parent to Child Model to display the data to my recyclerview. Any idea on how to solve it.

[image]

Comment: Have you upload your code somewhere ?

Comment: @Anubhav yeah bro in github. can you enlighten me to solve this.

Comment: @Anubhav can you check it this is the link (https://github.com/giodude28/CoroutineExample)

Comment: I will look into it, and get back to you.

Comment: I don't see the same model classes and even the api in the above repository.

Comment: @Anubhav can you enlighten me on how to call this api https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/search_all_teams.php?l=English%20Premier%20League using coroutine in kotlin. many thanks bro